# Rails includes not working on rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have to model where Room has many galleries and galleries belongs to room .. I want to get the two table information which is I used the includes active record ..

`room = Room.includes(:galleries).where(id: id_number)`

`room = Room.joins(:galleries).select("room.*, galleries.name").where(id: id_number`

the above code query is not getting the gallery part, it only get the room information. I am confused how to used the `includes` . I already watch the this ==> http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `Room.includes(:galleries).where(id: id_number).each { |room| room.galleries }` in your console and you will see that there is only one SQL query triggered to gather all `Gallery` records having `room_id` equal to your room(s)'s id(s).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to load the room and the galleries it has in one query, then

`room = Room.includes(:galleries).find(id_number)` will do the trick.

But I think you are misunderstanding what `joins` and `includes` are doing. You will always get one room object. If you want to access the galleries you'll have to call `room.galleries`.

Comment: Thank you sir.. How I can get both information in the two tables? room with galleries of photo?

Comment: You're getting it in one query. Calling `room.galleries` will not touch the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like:

```
room = Room.find(id_number).eager_load(:galleries)
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/eager_load